# Where does Opera store the image or the video files it downloads from internet?

Tags: windows, download, opera

where does Opera store the image or the video files it downloads from internet?

Can I get the exact location on Windows 2003 Machine?

Answer (score 3):

If you type opera:about in the address bar, it'll show you the path where various items (including the cache) are located. However, because it doesn't name them in the cache folder as friendly names, you're best typing opera:cache in the address bar and using the resulting page to access any individual images or videos it's downloaded while you've been browsing. The actual layout of this page will vary depending on what version of Opera you're running.